# Other reminder actions for events in Mozilla Lightning / Android Calendars (e-mail reminders)

Tags: thunderbird, android, calendar, lightning

I'd like to get email reminders for some of my events. Apparently, that's not currently supported in Thunderbird/Lightning (or Android).

I have a server that can access my calendar, if I can add custom reminder action in either Lightning or Android (ideally, both), a Python script on that server could easily do the job. But apparently neither of those two calendars supports adding custom reminder types?

There is an [old Lightning addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/custom-alarms/) to add custom alarm types, but it doesn't even install on recent TB versions.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem? Are there other addons I should be using? Should I use an alternative calendar on Android that can do this?